# How to add dir to PATH for executing programs

Tags: kde, path, kate

Kate requires omnisharp to be added to the PATH. I'm not sure which configuration file needs to be modified to include omnisharp in Kate's PATH.

Only when I start Kate through a console which contains omnisharp in its PATH it works. However, I don't think it's a good solution to simply call exec bash with a PATH export on the .desktop file, it looks like a botched job.

It's the LSP Client, more specifically, the one complaining. Is there an rc file for the LSP Client, perhaps? I'm completely lost.

Comment: *it looks like a botched job.* - looks ok to me.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov There's no workarounds, right? Like no "better" way of doing it, no .profile for executing programs or something like that... I guess it's the only way then, ok.

Comment: If a helper application is not installed system-wide, then there's no reason to treat as such. Let only the programs that need it see it. Of course, there's `/etc/profile.d/*.sh` if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: You can configure environment variables in `.desktop` files. Have you tried to set `$PATH` that way?